# Multiple Vuforia AR cameras in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to have two (stereo) AR cameras in Unity using Vuforia, so that I can display the left and right on different displays to create a 3D view on a 3D PluraView stereo screen.

However, when I set/change one AR camera in the Vuforia Configurator to the left webcam and the other to the right webcam, they both change to whichever webcam I last selected. How can I set it up so that each AR Camera GameObject can be assigned a different webcam input?

The AR Camera scripts don't appear to be exposed, or easily accessible, so it's difficult for me to provide further details of things I have tried yet.